# JavaScript body onunload not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have the following code:

```
function redirect(){
     window.location.href='logged_out_chat.php';
}
```

...in my header and the following body tag:

```
<body onunload="javascript:redirect();">
```

...when i try this on one laptop, it redirects as it is supposed to (when you click on any link), but on my other laptop, desktop and notebook it ignores the redirect and goes to any link you click on.
I have spent hours on this...all have the same browser. I was wondering if there is an alternative way i could redirect the user when they click on a link etc.

Comment: are you sure it's the EXACT same browser down to the dot-version number? Are your security settings the same in each? Running ad blockers on the others?

Answer (score 4):

What do you expect would happen?

When I close your page in my browser *you* get to redirect me to a page of your liking?

This goes againts security and user control. You shouldn't be able to interfere with the page when I close it.

The morale is don't rely on `onunload` to do anything non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

When a window unloads it stops processing everything, that means ajax requests, pending downloads etc, most even freeze animated gifs. Some browsers support `onbeforeunload`, but I completely agree with @Raynos you can't count on the event, so using it is not a good design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hijack onunload and redirect the user.  That would prevent the user from closing their browser, refreshing the page, or manually navigating to another site.  If that's what you are trying to do, you are out of luck.  All onunload is good for is asking the user if they are sure they want to leave the page.

If, however, you are trying to cause a clicked link to go to a different location, that's easy.  To change the link permanently:

```
myLink.href = 'logged_out_chat.php';
```

If you want to change the links temporarily, add a click handler that you can later remove:

```
function goToLoggedOutChat(e)
{
    e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    location.href = 'logged_out_chat.php';
}
mylink.onclick = goToLoggedOutChat;
```

To re-enable the link:

```
mylink.onclick = null;
```

To do it for every link on the page:

```
for (var i=0; i<document.links.length; i++)
{
    document.links[i].onclick = goToLoggedOutChat;
}
```