# Body onunload event

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, hta

I'm working on a HTA that should do some final modification on the `onunload` event. The event does not seem to be trigger.

Is the event still supported? Is there a IE event to know when the page is closed?

I checked around ([JavaScript body onunload not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651884/javascript-body-onunload-not-working)) a bit could not found the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try the `onbeforeunload` event.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using HTML 5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`?

A sample code for the onunload event is:

```
<body onunload="alert('The onunload event was triggered')">
</body>
```

Remember that the onunload event should be within the `<body>` or a `<framset>` tag.

Can you supply a link or some code so we can see what is going on and maybe advise more?

Comment: Sadly we need to be compatible with ould IE. 6 and up :(

Comment: Damn, sorry. IE6 is a pile of crap and very little works with it. Sorry I wish you luck with your problem.